# How to send post request in Ionic 2 for Node server run in localhost?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic2

In ionic I used service provider to access http.

**Service.ts** file is like this. **data is a json object.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Service {

constructor(public http: Http) {
   console.log('Hello Service Provider');
}

addNewPlace(data:any){
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  console.log(data);
  this.http.post("http://127.0.0.1:3000/postData/",data);
}
}
```

My node **app.js** file is like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.send("Hello_World");
});

app.post('/postData',function(req,res){
   console.log(">>>> "+req.body);
   res.json('Thank You');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');
});
```

Where is the place I wrong? I want to send data object to node server from service script and console it. But nothing happens with this code. And also no any errors!!!

My node server is running on port 3000. 
My ionic program is running on port 8100.

Comment: Can you show the format of your `data` object?

Comment: are you able to test the server with a rest client?

Comment: Where do you use `addNewPlace()`?

Comment: @Sampath data is a JSON object {lname:"dsds",description:"sdsdsd"}

Comment: @echonax addNewPlace() is in Page (Component)ts file. I called the addNewPlace() function from component.ts just import it.

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage can you add to your question how you are using it?

Comment: I found the solution. CORS is the problem, I install cors from npm package and add to that in my node file, now it work in good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem SOLVED! The problem is in CORS.

I installed cors and import that to my node file. Now it working perfectly.

```
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

added above code to my node file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach for that.

*Your page component.*

```
export class MyPage {

    constructor(public service : Service){}

         // entry method 
         myPostData(): void {
           this.service.postData("http://127.0.0.1:3000/postData/",data)
         }
    }
```

*Your service class.*

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {

         //post data
         postData(url: string, body: string): Observable<your-data-type> {
            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            return this.http.post(url, body, options)
              .map(this.extractData)
              .catch(this.handleError);
          }

         //to extract data
          private extractData(res: Response) {
            let body = res.json();
            return body || {};
          }

          //to handle error
          private handleError(error: Response | any) {
            let errMsg: string;
            if (error instanceof Response) {
              const body = error.json() || '';
              const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
              errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
            } else {
              errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
            }
            console.error(errMsg);
            return Observable.throw(errMsg);
          }

}
```